# object not updating on the view for google map on mouseover

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/cb9nwx06/7/

`<div id="info" ng-style="{'left':infoStyle.left,'top':infoStyle.top}">
    {{ infoStyle }}
    </div>`

infoStyle not updating in the view.

Comment: infoStyle not updating in the view

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cb9nwx06/15/